How can I tackle `Property 'zoom' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleDeclaration'.`
I have to use the zoom CSS property of an element, but TypeScript throws the following error:
Property 'zoom' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleDeclaration'.
on the following line:
const cssZoomOfTable = (+document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("[data-qa=table]")?.style?.zoom || 1).toFixed(2);
The TypeScript-related settings in package.json are these ones:

Any idea how can I resolve this?
What I tried so far is to put a comment with /* tslint:disable-next-line */ right above the problematic getting of zoom CSS property - which didn't work at all.

I get around css problems like this by using 'as' CssProperties on the key. Wrap the key in brackets. ['zoom' as keyof CssProperties]: 'value'

The zoom attribute was just added to the type definition for CSSStyleDeclaration in this commit on April 19 2024.
Since the most recent version of TypeScript (5.4.5) was released a bit before that (April 10 2024), there isn't a stable release yet that contains this update. This could be released in v5.4.6 but seems to be tagged for the v5.5 release.
In the mean time you can either use the 5.5 beta release or just use the // @ts-expect-error comment above.
